# Have to use sudo while using node command in osx

Tags: macos, node.js

I just installed node.js in osx, finding that I have to use sudo before executing any node command, which causes big inconvenience. I think the problem is that my current system account   does't have the permission to execute node command, which I guess could be resolved by authorisation. Yet, I don't know how to do it. Anyone knowing how to authorise? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you install node.js?

Comment: with pkg. Both `node` and `npm` has been installed in use/local/bin as default. I added the directory to PATH as well. `node` command can be executed only with `sudo`.